# std::packaged_task bug in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11

I found out that a `std::packaged_task` couldn't be pushed into a `std::vector` if the parameter type returns `void` in Visual Studio (2012, 2013, Nov 2013 CTP). For example,

```
typedef std::packaged_task<void()> packaged_task;

std::vector<packaged_task> tasks;
packaged_task package;
tasks.push_back(std::move(package));
```

The error messages are:

```
error C2182: '_Get_value' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2182: '_Val' : illegal use of type 'void'
error C2512: 'std::_Promise<int>' : no appropriate default constructor available
error C2665: 'std::forward' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

I think this is bug because this code snippet works if

1. the return type is not `void`,
2. it is compiled in XCode.

Are there solutions or other options in Visual Studio? I know that boost can be used to replace this.

Comment: Workaround: Why not use emplace_back

Comment: I can reproduce this with a simple `auto m = std::move(package);`. I suspect this is a MSVC bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this with a simple `auto m = std::move(package);`.

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::packaged_task<void()> packagedtask;
    packagedtask p1;
    packagedtask p2;
    p2 = std::move(p1); // does not cause the error
    auto p3 = std::move(p2); // causes the error
}
```

Trawling through the code, `packaged_task` has embedded typedefs as follows;

```
typedef typename _P_arg_type<_Ret>::type _Ptype;
typedef _Promise<_Ptype> _MyPromiseType;
```

`_P_arg_type` offers a non-void type when the return type is `void`. The `packaged_task` move constructor contains a reference to the internal `_Promise` as `_Promise<_Ret>`;

```
_MyPromise(_STD forward<_Promise<_Ret> >(_Other._MyPromise))
```

This then becomes `_Promise<void>` which in turn generates further invalid code that generates the list of errors seen. It should probably be;

```
_MyPromise(_STD forward<_MyPromiseType >(_Other._MyPromise))
// possibly even using a move
```

As the move assignment operator does.

As a workaround, consider adding a "dummy" or "unusable" return type of some sort;

```
struct unusable {};
```

Or just simply an `int` or boost as you have already suggested.

Comment: Thanks, introducing a dummy is nice idea.